# Python style: lowercase class names for "namespaces"?

Tags: python, coding-style

I know the [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) convention for class names is `ClassName`. But we often use small classes as pseudo-namespaces, enums etc. In other words, not a real class that you're going to instantiate. We've opted for a lowercase naming convention for such "classes", because they're really a namespace/enum name.

Does anyone else have in-house styles for this, or other ways of achieving the same thing?

An example:

```
import urllib2

class config:  # pseudo-namespace for module-level config variables
    api_url = 'http://example.com/api'
    timeout = 1.5
    debug = True

class countries:  # pseudo-enum
    new_zealand = 1
    united_states = 2

def func():
    if config.debug:
        print 'Calling func()'
    return urllib2.urlopen(config.api_url)
```

Comment: Good question, I just implemented a namespace this way a couple days ago and wasn't sure what to do.  I would normally use a separate module but in this case I didn't want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all enums and constants, I prefer to use capitalized versions.

```
class COUNTRIES:  # pseudo-enum
    NEW_ZEALAND = 1
    UNITED_STATES = 2
```

It is still ok with me, if the class name is not all capitalized. Since, any way it is tied up with the enum  values. I am always going to use it like `Countries.NEW_ZEALAND`, which tells me that it is an enum.

```
class Countries:  # pseudo-enum
    NEW_ZEALAND = 1
    UNITED_STATES = 2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also create a module named `config` with the following content:

```
api_url = 'http://example.com/api'
timeout = 1.5
debug = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
class PseudoNamespace: pass

config = PseudoNamespace()
config.api_url = 'http://example.com/api'
config.timeout = 1.5
config.debug = True

countries = PseudoNamespace()
config.new_zealand = 1
config.united_states = 2
```

if you really care about the PEP?

Answer (score 1):

I use dictionaries instead:

```
config = dict(
    api_url = 'http://example.com/api',
    timeout = 1.5,
    debug = True)

countries = dict(
    new_zealand = 1,
    united_states = 2)
```

If you find attribute access cumbersome in a Python `dict`, try an [`attrdict`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/361668-attrdict-a-dict-whose-items-can-also-be-accessed-a/):

```
class attrdict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self
```

It allows to access dictionary entries with keys that are valid identifiers as attributes, e.g. `config.api_url` instead of `config["api_url"]`.

Of course I use lower-case names for these.